# How to delete all data in elasticsearch using java in integration test cases?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, micronaut

I have `Micronaut` application connecting to elasticsearch using [java-client API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html), we are using [ElasticsearchClient](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.0.1/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchClient.html) to stores and retrieve the data into elastic search.

I'm writing integration test cases using `@MicronautTest` annotation by spinning up docker using `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: es-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.0
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - node.store.allow_mmap=false
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
   ports:
     - "9200:9200"
```

The problem in below test class is, for every test cases we are inserting data and since previous test data is not cleaning up, some of the test cases are failing with in correct results. My question to delete before every test case execution ?

**ElasticSearchTest**

```
@MicronautTest
public class ElasticSearchTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void test1() {

    // inserting some test data into ElasticSearch

    //mockmvc API call and asserting response
   }

  @Test
  public void test2()  {
   // inserting some test data into ElasticSearch
  

  //mockmvc API call and asserting response
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For in this use case you can use `@Before` in junit-4 and `@BeforeEach` in junit-5 to clean up the data before any test case execution ([baeldung artical)](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall).

As first step, you can inject `ElasticsearchClient` and create [Query](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.0.1/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/_types/query_dsl/Query.html) with MatchAllQuery

```
 @Inject
 ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient

 @BeforeEach
 public void setUp() {

    Query matchAll = new Query.Builder()
            .matchAll(new MatchAllQuery.Builder().build())
            .build()
    DeleteByQueryRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteByQueryRequest.Builder()
            .index("_all")
            .query(matchAll)
            .build()

    elasticsearchClient.deleteByQuery(deleteRequest).deleted()

 }
```